# DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") does not account my format

Tags: c#, datetime, tostring

This is the code I have:

```
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(55).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

The string I get from that code is:

```
"16.09.2013 19:45:03"
```

The question is, why the string is not in the format I've provided?

Comment: `/` means default date separator, so it's associated with your current culture

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use this:

```
DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(55).ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

because `/` means default date separator, so it's associated with your current culture. So know it will use always `/` here, no matter of current culture.

Read more [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

Comment: I just would add also the time format: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(55).ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH':'mm':'ss")